# Why would a computer game slow down an unrelated COM port?

Tags: c#, serial-port, lag, steam

## Problem:

So I have a physical device with buttons and joysticks on it, and I'm using it to move the mouse around and click on icons, etc.

To do this I have a C# program that reads a COM port and uses InputSimulator to fake keyboard and mouse actions. (Btw this app is a graphical application with its own window, since it also displays debug data on the screen.)

This works fine in Windows, in that I can use it to navigate around the OS, open programs, etc. I'm outputting a variable "maxTimeBetweenReadings" and it doesn't really go above 20 or 30ms.

However, I then open Steam and run a computer game. My device works fine at first and I can move around the start menu. But on entering a level, comms from the device becomes incredibly choppy and the game is unplayable. My maxTimeBetweenReadings value shoots up to over a second.

## Things I have tried:

- I have tried using the real mouse and keyboard, which is still perfectly smooth, so I know it's not that the game is slowing down my whole computer.
- I have tried setting the priority of my C# program to Realtime (though I don't want to do this in production) and the priority of the Thread it spawns to Highest. This makes no difference that I can see.
- I have commented out all other activity (writing/reading files, etc) in the C# program, even though I don't think that should make a difference at all. Again no difference, but then I wasn't hopeful.

My understanding is that Windows has claimed the COM port for my C# program and now won't let anything else talk to it, so even if the game wants to interfere with it for some reason, it shouldn't be able to?

And even if the game was somehow able to mess around and interrupt the comms, wouldn't the fact that the C# program is running at Realtime priority mean that the game should never be given a chance to do so?

However there are obviously gaps in my understanding, because it doesn't line up with what I'm seeing.

We need to be able to give away this device with the reassurance that it can work with ANY game, no matter how said game was implemented, no matter what awkward things it tries to do.

If I have to go game by game to make sure they aren't interfering somehow (and I still don't understand how they can) then I'll be here for a thousand years.

Comment: Interessting question. Did you do any of the software parts yourself?

Comment: Yeah, the C# program is mine.

Comment: Allright.. really cool thing though. However i'm not so sure if I'm able to write suitable answer to this question. May you grap the relevant code from your c# application, put it here and try to give us some way to reproduce the problem. I know im asking a lot, but I think your question will have a better chance of getting an answer. Right now, I can only say: Maybe you're doing something wrong ;)

Comment: Implement serial port using Asynchronous Read (not Synchronous).  The results is probably choppy because the sender is not responding quickly or you are not sending commands to server regularly (which will be fixed using Asynchronous methods).  Also do no put any waits (or sleep, or timers) in your code which also is cause for choppy results.

Comment: @jdweng What I don't understand is why would that be affected by other running processes? If it worked perfectly before the game is launched, and no one knows how the game is screwing it up, why would we expect Async behave any differently to Sync?

Comment: You have a master (client) slave (server) communications.  So server doesn't respond until client sends a message.  So if your server is not running smoothly you aren't sending messages in which results in you not receiving messages.  Using Synchronous methods you are blocking which is delaying you from receiving.  It is a Chicken and Egg problem (which comes first).  So if you don't send you don't receive.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, but at Realtime priority, the server should be running as smoothly as physically possible, shouldn't it? What I'm not clear on is how the game is able to disrupt this?

Comment: The server is a dumb device and does not do anything until a client sends a message/command.  The server may display current state but eventually it will not have any data to change state or get flooded with commands from client so it is doing too much processing and hangup.

Comment: @jdweng I still can't see how that's related to my problem. What you're talking about happens when the C# program doing the polling gets randomly stopped and started by Windows as it gives time to other processes, yes? But if the C# program has Realtime priority then it should be taking a whole core to itself, and never getting interrupted for any other process (or am i wrong, and that's not what would happen?) In which case there should never be this kind of hang up.

Comment: If your program is "waiting" for data (in a blocking method) then it is going to stall which is an underflow.

Comment: @jdweng Why is it happening when the game is running and not when the game is not?

Comment: Because you hitting some blocking code.  When the game is not running you are not getting messages from server.

Comment: @jdweng But the game is totally unrelated to the server! The C# program is sitting and running happily (on its own core, because of the Realtime priority), and entirely separately, I'm opening Steam and starting the game. Nothing inside the C# program references or waits on the game. The game is (should be) forbidden from touching the COM port. Where then is the blocking code?

Comment: You said "However, I then open Steam and run a computer game".  Where is the stream input coming from?  Does the program run as a stand-alone or need to be connected to a server?  Are you calling any blocking methods?  Do you have any timers that are waiting for inputs (where are inputs coming from)?  Are you flooding the server with commands so server is running slow?

Comment: @jdweng C# program runs, spawns a Thread that opens a COM port and loops forever, sending a msg to the device and updating some state variables based on the response. C# program then (in its main thread) has a Timer that ticks every 10ms and uses InputSimulator to cause keyboard,mouse events based on the state. This works fine until the game runs. The game is an entirely unrelated program to the C# program. The InputSimulator'd events let me control the player in the game - or should do, if the choppiness didn't happen.

Comment: samson. How about you just show us some code?

Comment: @LuckyLikey I'll be able to later, am not at the right computer today.

Comment: @LuckyLikey Done now, I've pasted out the relevant bits of the program.

Comment: @jdweng I have now had a chance to test it using Asynchronous Read and Write and am getting exactly the same results.

Comment: How do you know that each receive message is received completely?  Do you check for a termination character?  You will not always receive a complete message every time you read.  So ParseBikeResponse() must check to see if the termination character is in the buffer and if it is not in the buffer do not process.  Then change following : bike.LastCommunication += buffer;

Comment: @jdweng I am reading exactly the right number of bytes in the asynchronous version I've just tested. But that is a problem totally unrelated to the fact that the program _works fine_ until the game is started, then _stops working_ when the game loads its first level. The game _should not be allowed_ to interfere with the COM port.

Comment: Is there any way to give myself the same priority as mouse and keyboard events? Those do not get choppy in the same way as my device does.

Comment: How much CPU is the game taking up (when in a level)?  My guess is your program has lower priority and all your PC resources are being allocated to the game.  You're C# program is only running when the PC allocates enough resources for it, which is why it would seem "choppy".